# cv2.stereoCalibrate criteria error

Tags: opencv, camera, calibration

I'm trying to perform a stereo calibration of two cameras using opencv3.4.
I have performed the calibration of the two single cameras from which I obtained the `mtxleft` and right to use in stereocalibrate.

But I get the following error:

> in <module>
>       criteria = termination_criteria_extrinsics
>
> error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3083:
>   error: (-215) nimages > 0 && nimages == (int)imagePoints1.total() && (!imgPtMat2 || nimages == (int)imagePoints2.total())
>   in function cv::collectCalibrationData

This is my code:

```
termination_criteria_extrinsics =  (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + 
cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-5)

ret, mtx, dist, mtx2, dist2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
  objpoints_l, 
  imgpoints_l ,imgpoints_r, mtxL, distL, mtxR, distR,
  gray_l.shape[::-1],
  flags = flags,
  criteria = termination_criteria_extrinsics 
)
```

Does anyone know what the cause could be?